# SAMA5D27C-D1G-CU using XTAL with different frequency than in the reference design

Tags: microcontroller, oscillator, crystal, microprocessor

I am using [SAMA5D27C-D1G-CU](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/atsama5d27c-d1g) in my design. Below is the image from the reference design.

You can see that [Y1](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/ndk-america-inc/NX2016SA-24MHZ-EXS00A-CS10820/9172021) is 24 MHz. I already have a 25 MHz XTAL in my inventory.

1. May I know can I use 25 MHz instead of 24 MHz given in the reference design? Will it cause any issues?

For [Y2](https://www.digikey.in/en/products/detail/ndk-america,-inc/NX2012SA-32.768KHZ-EXS00A-MU00530/9172082?utm_adgroup=General&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=Dynamic%20Search_EN_Product&utm_term=&productid=&utm_content=General&utm_id=go_cmp-146895304_adg-9173957824_ad-549894352681_dsa-400671891782_dev-c_ext-56038236110_prd-_sig-Cj0KCQjw4bipBhCyARIsAFsieCw8eOArTwZJ3p2wExswPH2HintAPKXo0uP0GV9luCaiE_iBcZzyfiYaAuXVEALw_wcB&gclid=Cj0KCQjw4bipBhCyARIsAFsieCw8eOArTwZJ3p2wExswPH2HintAPKXo0uP0GV9luCaiE_iBcZzyfiYaAuXVEALw_wcB) you can see that the load capacitance is 8 pF. I already have 10 pF with our inventory.

2. Can I use 10 pF instead of 8 pF? Will my IC work properly?

[image]

Comment: You’d want to read the documentation to fully understand if 24MHz is especially significant. I’d hazard to guess it is probably related to USB.  So whilst your 25MHz crystal should oscillate and clock the device, USB may simply not work.

Comment: What does the data sheet say about the maximum crystal frequency?

Comment: 24Mhz is maximum

Comment: (Note: Please [edit] your question if you clarify things. This is not a forum, comments are not supposed to hold new information.) -- Then you are trying to run the MCU out of specification. Commonly it will work with such a small difference (4%), but there is no guarantee. And you should take Kartman's comment into account. Why don't you simply try?